# Run a service in background continuously

Tags: android, android-intentservice

Run a service in background continuously. For example, a service has to be kicked off which will display a toast message 20 seconds once even if the app is closed.

```
public class AppService extends IntentService {

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public AppService() {
        super("AppService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SystemClock.sleep(20000);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to ensure Service still running even after app is closed, then use  Foreground Service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below code works for me...

```
public class AppService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Comment: This will not work on from Android Oreo API level 26, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557840/run-a-service-in-background-continuously/63807172#63807172

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer will not work on from Android 8.0 (API level 26), see the android's background limitations [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

**Modification in Accepted Answer:**

**1:** You have to invoke the service's `startForeground()` method within 5 seconds after starting the service. To do this, you can call `startForeground()` in `onCreate()` method of service.

```
public class AppService extends Service {
    ....
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        startForeground(9999, Notification())
    }

    ....
}
```

**2:** You must call `startForegroundService()` instead of `startService()` by checking API level from where you want to start the service.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: What is Notification() !? Are you missing the 'new' keyword?

Comment: @wEight Notification object. Yes forget to add `new` keywork as I was thinking of Kotlin language.

Answer (score 2):

This code work for me..

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {

    public static final int notify = 300000;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 5 Minute)
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();   //run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Timer mTimer = null;    //timer handling

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (mTimer != null) // Cancel if already existed
            mTimer.cancel();
        else
            mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);   //Schedule task
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTimer.cancel();    //For Cancel Timer
        Log.d("service is ","Destroyed");
    }

    //class TimeDisplay for handling task
    class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("service is ","running");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, where you declare your service, add:

```
android:process=":processname"
```

This lets the service run on a separate process and thus it will not be killed with the app.

You can then chose if you want to use foreground. It will show a persistent notification, but reduces the likelihood if the service being killed.

Further, if you want to create a continuously running service, use `Service`, **NOT** `IntentService`. IntentService stops when it is finished doing its action.